# Should I create 3 divs if I have two images on the sides of my container?

Tags: html, css, web

[image]

They are highlighted in red. Those are transparent images in my PSD.

Should I make it like this:

```
<div class="left-div"><img src="food_img1.ong"/></div>
<div class="inner-div">Here goes main container</div>
<div class="right-div"><img src="food_img2.ong"/></div>
```

Or is there any better way? 
Thanks in advance. I am a newbie in PSD-2-HTML, so your support is much appreciated.

Comment: You can do it with one `div` that has two background images. The content would be the second `div` inside the first. `background: url(left.png) left no-repeat, url(right.png) left no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use one div with one image by placing that div inside body with an absolute position.

```
<body>
<div class="image_div"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
</body>

.container{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
.image_div{
  width:100%;
  background-color:blue; //use background-image:(image.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover; //optional
  background-position:50% 50%; //optional
  height:300px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vct7Lfm2/)